# Show that for $2$ vertices $u$ and $v$ have the same score in a tournament $T$ then $u$ and $v $ belong to the same strong component of order $k$

Tags: graph-theory

a)  Show that for $2$ vertices $u$ and $v$ have the same score in a tournament $T$ then $u$ and $v $ belong to the same strong component of order $k$

b)  Prove that every regular tournament is strong

> Define the relation on $V(T)$ by $u$ is related to $v$ if there is both $u-v$ path and $v-u$ path in $T$. This is an equivalent relation so this relation partition $V(T)$ into equivalent classes $V_1, V_2,..., V_k$  $(k\geq 1)$. Let $S_i= T[V_i]$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$, then $S_i$ are called **strong components** of $T$

a)

From $u$ and $v$ have the same score I can see that $od(u)=od(v)$. So there is a path from $u$ and $v$ to other $k$ vertices, but how do I know there is a path from $u$ to $v$ and from $v$ to $u$  from these info?

b)

Let $T$ be a regular tournament then for every $v$ in $T$ , $id(v)=od(v)$. A tournament is a directed graph, and a directed graph such that for every $v$ in $T$ , $id(v)=od(v)$ is Eulerian. So a regular tournament is strong because it contain an Eulerian cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof of part a:

By symmetry we may assume that the arrow between $u$ and $v$ is directed $uv$.
Not counting any other arrows we see that $u$ is ahead in outdegree, so $v$ needs to
have at least one arrow to a vertex $w$ such that $uw$ is not an arrow.
But then $wu$ is an arrow and $vwu$ is a directed path from $v$ to $u$.

The proof of part b looks fine.

Comment: in my book we called $u \to w$, $u$ beats $w$, so by saying $uw$ id not an arrow, you mean $w\to u$ or $w$ beat $u$?

Comment: It does not really matter how you call it. The only thing relevant is that in a tournament and two vertices $u$ and $v$ exactly one of $uv$, $vu$ is an arrow of the tournament.

Comment: is it ok if I assume $od(u)=od(v)=k$? Because this problem want me to show that they are in the same strong component of order $k$. Your proof show that they are in the same strong component, but do I have to do some extra part about order $k$?

Comment: The $k$ in the title of your question (the order of the component to which $u$ and $v$ belong)
and the $k$ in the definition you quote (the number of strong components) must be different.
For example, in a consistently oriented triangle, which is strong,
all vertices have outdegree 1.
Nevertheless the only strong component has order 3.
Therefore I assumed that $k$ was just some meaningless variable.
If this turns out to be wrong, please clarify the exact question.
Maybe it helps if you literally quote the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I copied the question word by word from the book, I guess I just misunderstand the order $k$ part